# For loop to plot multiple variables in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have ran code where I first filter variables and then run a plot, see code below

```
pl1 = mydata %>%
  filter(CID =="1", NID =="1", SID =="301", WID =="1")
  
ggplot(pl1, aes(x=Timestamp, y=T_Var , colour=SID)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=.4, linetype="dashed", color = "red") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=.7, linetype="dashed", color = "maroon")
```

Were each of the of the filtered items are as follows
CID from 1 - 30
NID from 1 - 8
SID from 301 - 310
WID from 1 - 9
T_Var is the target variable

I know this is a lot of plots, but I was wondering if this can be done with a for loop.

Comment: Yes it can. The only gotcha is that you need to explicitly `print()` the ggplot object within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this:

```
for(cid in 1:30) {
  for(nid in 1:8) {
   data <- mydata %>% filter(CID==cid, NID==nid, ...)
   p <- ggplot(mydata ....)
   print(p) # Or save to file using ggsave(), png() or pdf()
  }
}
```

While filtering you should check if it is necessary to convert number to strings. I dont know what type is you dataframe columns. So instead of `filter(CID==cid)`, you need to write `filter(CID==as.character(cid)`.

Maybe there is a cleaner way to do it. Stacking multiple for loop can make the combinatorial explode...
You can also use layout panels (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) to make multiple subplots but with the number of plots you want to build, it might be non appropriate.

Comment: This code works for me thanks very much. I was trying to save with ggsave but I keep getting errors. I know that there are multiple plots and I think that his were I am getting the error